# Counting 2-partitions of $\{1, 2, \cdots, n\}$ of equal size and sum

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, set-partition

The following question solves the existence of such a partition: [Partitioning $\{1,\cdots,k\}$ into $p$ subsets with equal sums](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1559650/partitioning-1-cdots-k-into-p-subsets-with-equal-sums). However, I'm trying to count how many such 2-partitions exist. Specifically,

Let $X = \{1, \cdots, 2n\}$. How many unique $S \subset X$ has cardinality $n$ and $\sum S = 2n^2+n$?

I'm trying to count the number of exact sequences on finite dimensional vector spaces $\mathbb R^1, \cdots, \mathbb R^{2n}$.

Comment: Do you mean $\Sigma S = n^2 + \frac{1}{2}n$? We always have

$$
\Sigma S \leq \sum_{i=n+1}^{2n}i = \sum_{i=1}^{n}(i+n) = n^2 + \sum_{i=1}^{n}i = n^2 + \frac{n^2 + n}{2} = \frac{3}{2}n^2 + \frac{1}{2}n < 2n^2 + n.
$$

By the way, the total sum $2n^2 + n$ has the parity of $n$ so we could restrict ourselves to the case in which $n$ is even.