# How to divide numbers $1,\ldots,n$ into $3$ equal groups?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The sum of numbers $1,\ldots,n$ is equal $n(n+1)/2$ so it will be divisible by $3$ only for $n=3k$ and $n=3k+2$. I am interested is that partition always possible for that cases.

Let's exclude $n=2$ and $n=3$ because clearly it is not possible to do partition them.

For $n=8$ we can do $\{4,8\}$, $\{1,5,6\}$ and $\{2,3,7\}$.

Comment: A full answer has been given here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1559650/partitioning-1-cdots-k-into-p-subsets-with-equal-sums/1559713#1559713.

Comment: If $6|n$ you can do it by $\{n,1,n-3,4,\ldots\}, \{n-1,2,n-4,5,\ldots\}, \{n-2, 3, n-5,6,\ldots\}$